# do we need to dispose entity context object

Tags: asp.net

I am building [website](http://www.bollywoodblockbustermovies.com) and using entity framework.  My question is regarding the entity context object usage.  Is it best practice to create entity context object in each method or create it on page load and save it in viewstate?  Will that be overhead if I create entity context object in each method?

Comment: Lots of questions on this topic already: see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=entity+context+lifetime

Answer (score 1):

You should create and dispose the ObjectContext with each page request, unless you profile your web site and it shows that you're having performance problems with doing so.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your answer.  Let's say there is some logic in page load to retrieve the data and button click save the information in database.  So should I have to create a private entity context object and use it in page load and later in button click event or both should use their own object?

Comment: Either way is fine. Having a separate object for each event is simpler and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

> create it on page load and save it in viewstate?

Don't do this. (please, not ever)

Whether you create and dispose *per method* or not is open for debate, but it needs to at least be *per request.*